# can django support group by some columns at the same time sum on other columns

Tags: python, django

just like the query below :

```
select sum(T.a), sum(T.b) from Table T group by T.c , T.d
```

is there any way in django support this kind of query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is close:

```
class Test(models.Model):                                                                                          
    class Meta:                                                                                                    
        app_label = 'ignore'                                                                                       
        db_table = 'T'                                                                                             
    a = models.IntegerField()                                                                                      
    b = models.IntegerField()                                                                                      
    c = models.IntegerField()                                                                                      
    d = models.IntegerField()      

result = Test.objects.values('c', 'd').annotate(Sum('a'), Sum('b'))
print str(result.query)
```

results with:

> SELECT "T"."c", "T"."d", SUM("T"."a") AS "a_*sum", SUM("T"."b") AS "b*_sum" FROM "T" GROUP BY "T"."c", "T"."d", "T"."c", "T"."d"

Why the GROUP BY values are repeated, I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Sum
>>> from myapp.models import T
>>> results = T.objects.values('c', 'd').annotate(Sum('a'), Sum('b'))
>>> print results.query
SELECT "myapp_t"."c", "myapp_t"."d", SUM("myapp_t"."a") AS "a__sum", SUM("myapp_t"."b") AS "b__sum" FROM "myapp_t" GROUP BY "myapp_t"."c", "myapp_t"."d"
```

See the [Django documentation on aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, django supports it , its documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values)